# AttributeError: module 'app.models.PostModel' has no attribute '_sa_class_manager'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I was trying to add flask-admin to my application. I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/sanifss/4264239664238C2B/Projects/Personal/Portfolio/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = create_app()

  File "/run/media/sanifss/4264239664238C2B/Projects/Personal/Portfolio/app/__init__.py", line 71, in create_app
    admin.add_view(ModelView(PostModel, db.session))
  File "/home/sanifss/.local/share/virtualenvs/Portfolio-UVOeSvIO/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 327, in __init__
    super(ModelView, self).__init__(model, name, category, endpoint, url, static_folder,
  File "/home/sanifss/.local/share/virtualenvs/Portfolio-UVOeSvIO/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._refresh_cache()
  File "/home/sanifss/.local/share/virtualenvs/Portfolio-UVOeSvIO/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 895, in _refresh_cache
    self._list_columns = self.get_list_columns()
  File "/home/sanifss/.local/share/virtualenvs/Portfolio-UVOeSvIO/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1035, in get_list_columns
    only_columns=self.column_list or self.scaffold_list_columns(),
  File "/home/sanifss/.local/share/virtualenvs/Portfolio-UVOeSvIO/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 418, in scaffold_list_columns
    for p in self._get_model_iterator():
  File "/home/sanifss/.local/share/virtualenvs/Portfolio-UVOeSvIO/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 354, in _get_model_iterator
    return model._sa_class_manager.mapper.iterate_properties
AttributeError: module 'app.models.PostModel' has no attribute '_sa_class_manager'
```

I think it could be some dependency issue between SQLAlchemy and Flask-Admin. But cannot figure out what exactly is going wrong and how to fix.

My PostModel

```
# src/models/PostModel.py
import datetime

from marshmallow import Schema, fields
from slugify import slugify

from . import db


class PostModel(db.Model):
    """
    Post Model
    """

    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    slug = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)
    contents = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey('users.id'),
        nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    modified_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.slug = slugify(data.get('title'))
        self.contents = data.get('contents')
        self.owner_id = data.get('owner_id')
        self.created_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        self.modified_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

    def save(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()

    def update(self, data):
        for key, item in data.items():
            setattr(self, key, item)
        self.modified_at = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        db.session.commit()

    def delete(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_blogposts():
        return PostModel.query.all()

    @staticmethod
    def get_one_post(id):
        return PostModel.query.get(id)

    @staticmethod
    def get_one_post_by_slug(id):
        return PostModel.query.filter_by(slug=id).first()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)
```

Db is  created under models/**init**.py

```
# app/models/__init__.py

from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# initialize our db
db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
```

at last my app

```
import logging.config
from os import environ

from celery import Celery
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_cors import CORS

from app.models import PostModel, UserModel

from .config import config as app_config
from .models import bcrypt, db

celery = Celery(__name__)


def create_app():
    """
    Create app
    """
    # loading env vars from .env file
    load_dotenv()
    APPLICATION_ENV = get_environment()

    logging.config.dictConfig(app_config[APPLICATION_ENV].LOGGING)

    # app initializations
    app = Flask(app_config[APPLICATION_ENV].APP_NAME)
    app.config.from_object(app_config[APPLICATION_ENV])

    CORS(app, resources={r'/api/*': {'origins': '*'}})

    celery.config_from_object(app.config, force=True)
    # celery is not able to pick result_backend and hence using
    # update
    celery.conf.update(
        result_backend=app.config['RESULT_BACKEND'])

    # Other initializations
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)

    # migration
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    # Blueprints
    from .views.CoreView import core as core_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(
        core_blueprint,
        url_prefix='/api/v1/core'
    )

    from .views.UserView import user_api as user_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(
        user_blueprint,
        url_prefix='/api/v1/users'
    )

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        """
        Blog endpoint
        """
        return 'Server is up and running'

    # Admin
    admin = Admin(app)
    admin.add_view(sqla.ModelView(PostModel, db.session))
    return app


def get_environment():
    return environ.get('APPLICATION_ENV') or 'development'
```

I am new to flask and flask-admin any help is much appreciated.